# Colour features by hex code in attribute field in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

If I have a set of features in ArcGIS Online (currently using Map Viewer Classic but I'd be prepared to switch to the new Map Viewer if needs be) with a column in the attribute table containing hex colour codes (eg '#FF00FF'), is there a way to colour features based on these attribute values?

To get the desired outcome at the moment, I'm having to symbolise by attribute, then manually change the colour for each feature to match the colour in the HEX_COLOR attribute column - there is an option to put in your own hex code so getting the right colour isn't an issue, but it still needs me to go through manually and change it for each feature.

[image: screenshot]

I am able to do this in Pro using symbol property connections and attribute mapping, but when I share the data from Pro into ArcGIS Online as a Web Layer, all this symbology is lost.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.